# Robots.txt is not serving

Tags: django, django-urls, robots.txt

I am using Python with django framework for a web application. 
I have made a urls.py entry to serve the robots.txt file, however for some reason it seems like it's not able to serve it up.

```
url(r'^robots.txt$', 'support.views.robot_file',name="robot_file"),
```

this method works for sitemap.xml which has a very similar entry works

```
url(r'^sitemap.xml', 'support.views.sitemap_file',name="sitemap_file"),
```

Which leads me to believe only serving robots.txt file is a problem as when I change it to serve robot.txt it works.

Can somebody could throw some pointers in as to why it would be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be using apache - there's probably something in your apache config that is breaking robots.txt - maybe an "Alias /robots.txt /somewhere/that/doesn't/exist.txt" perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are right I checked in the apache setting and I was indeed having it pointed out to a static file location where robots.txt wasn't present. Thanks for all the help. After fixing it, robots.txt is coming properly. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `robots.txt`. If that is a copy-paste, that is your problem.

It also could be your web-server configuration is trying to server `robots.txt` from somewhere else. What specific error do you receive when you request `robots.txt`?

Also, format your code using `ctrl-k` or the code button in the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: my bad let me format the codeurl(r'^robots.txt', 'support.views.robot_file',name="robot_file"),

Answer (score 0):

My working solution is like the following:

```
(r'^robots.txt$', 'my_project.views.robots'),
```

my view:

```
def robots(request):
    template = 'robots.txt'
    context = {}
    return render_to_response(template, context,
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Hi Tom, 
It still gives the error. You can check it at 
https://vialogues.com/robots.txt

Comment: Do you have a robots.txt in your root template folder?

Comment: settings.py RUNMODE = 'dev' to see detail error message? whereas I do not expect something else as the error you see now.

Comment: Since you are getting a 404 it seems as it does not find the specified template. Thus the robots.txt is probably missing in the template folder.

Comment: It exists in the folder if I change the regular expression in urls.py from ^robots.txt$ to say for e.g. ^robots$ it works. only the name robots.txt is giving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best for static files to be served by the webserver you're using. In my opinion it just creates an unneeded overhead for Django.

Comment: I am surely doing the static way. Thanks for pointing it out Chris.

Comment: What if you are not have an access to your server configuration?